# Why are there undefined references to PPP_GetInterface, PPP_ShutdownModule, and PPP_InitializeModule

Tags: google-nativeclient

I am trying compile a pexe file using the portable native client. I am following the instructions at this page:

https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/devcycle/building

I am trying to build a pexe and link it with a static lib as shown on the page. My command line is as follows.

```
/home/adev/opt/nacl_sdk/pepper_37/toolchain/linux_pnacl/bin/pnacl-clang++ -o pim-pnacl.pexe pim-pnacl.o -L/home/adev/opt/nacl_sdk/pepper_37/lib/pnacl/Release -lppapi_cpp -lppapi -L../libpidec -lpidec
```

and I get the following errors.

```
/home/adev/opt/nacl_sdk/pepper_37/toolchain/linux_pnacl/sdk/lib/libppapi_stub.a: error: undefined reference to 'PPP_GetInterface'
/home/adev/opt/nacl_sdk/pepper_37/toolchain/linux_pnacl/sdk/lib/libppapi_stub.a: error: undefined reference to 'PPP_ShutdownModule'
/home/adev/opt/nacl_sdk/pepper_37/toolchain/linux_pnacl/sdk/lib/libppapi_stub.a: error: undefined reference to 'PPP_InitializeModule'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, the problem was in the pim-pnacl.o it needed to be compiled with the -c flag. This is the correct way to compile a single .o file:

```
/home/adev/opt/nacl_sdk/pepper_37/toolchain/linux_pnacl/bin/pnacl-clang++ -o pim-pnacl.o pim-pnacl.cc -O2 -I/home/adev/opt/nacl_sdk/pepper_37/include -c
```

I had omitted the -c and this caused linker problems.